# Why '$(document).ready(function()' is not working for this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have JQuery script that is working when I click the button. But I am trying to do like when page is loaded to work but somehow even I tried  `$(document).ready(function()` at the beginning it doesn't work and I didn't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
<div class="skill">
    <button style="width: 300px;">Show value</button>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner" data-progress="100%">
<h2 id="demo">€0</h2>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
$('.skill').on('click', 'button', function(){
    var skillBar = $(this).siblings().find('.inner');
    var skillVal = skillBar.attr("data-progress");
    $(skillBar).animate({  height: skillVal}, 2100);
});
</script>
```

Here is the code. How can I modify to run it without clicking the button?
With this, when I click the button it is working well but if its to modify and remove button to make it by itself it does not work.

I want to make it like this:

```html
<div class="skill">
 <button style="width: 300px;">Show value</button>
 <div class="outer">
  <div class="inner" data-progress="100%">
   <h2 id="demo">€0</h2>
   <div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var skillBar = $(this).siblings().find('.inner');
 var skillVal = skillBar.attr("data-progress");
 $(skillBar).animate({ height: skillVal}, 2100); }); 
</script>'
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that *isn't* working?

Comment: I want to make it like this:   '<div class="skill">
    <button style="width: 300px;">Show value</button>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner" data-progress="100%">
<h2 id="demo">€0</h2>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var skillBar = $(this).siblings().find('.inner');
    var skillVal = skillBar.attr("data-progress");
    $(skillBar).animate({  height: skillVal}, 2100);
});
</script>'

Comment: @ÖzkanAdar you can click the `edit` button if you want to add details

Comment: can you provide a working demo.. and what error you are getting in console?

Comment: there is no `ready` in this? Also I think your misunderstanding what it does. I'd suggest you read [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: `$(document).ready` has a concept of `this` - but it's not what you're expecting. What do you think `$(this).siblings()` does when the code isn't running in the context of a button?

Comment: You need to wrap your animation code in `$('.skill').each(function() { ... });` in order for `$(this)` to work as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qca0pLkz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var skillBar = $(this).siblings().find('.inner'); won't work because
>   on load, $(this) is not defined. You have to add class , tag or id in
>   place of $(this)

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           var skillBar = $('.inner');
            var skillVal = skillBar.attr("data-progress");
            $(skillBar).animate({
                height: skillVal
            }, 2100);
            alert('a');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="skill">
        <button style="width: 300px;">Show value</button>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner" data-progress="100%">
                <h2 id="demo">€0</h2>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wanted to make it without button. When I remove button it is not working. I changed var skillBar = $('button').siblings().find('.inner'); to var skillBar = $(this).siblings().find('.inner'); and still didn't work. But like you did, it is working only except for background image I need to click somewhere to load. Animation is coming itself but without background unless I click

Comment: can you provide a working demo, so that we can check? @ÖzkanAdar

Comment: @ÖzkanAdar , check my updated code.. check line to  var skillBar = $('.inner');

Comment: `$(this) is not defined` - to clarify, `this` *is* defined, it's just not the button.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur I would want to ask another question a bit more complex, could you help me please?

Comment: Yes, you can ask

Comment: @AmanjotKaur I am making this with css to put animation. According to animation whichever percentage is it, percentage will be fill up according to that. I do have css animation already. But I could not move background filling alongside this percentage.

Comment: if you can share a working example, it would be great and we can find the issue than in the code...

Comment: is it possible to send you the whole code about this issue? @AmanjotKaur

Comment: you can post a new question and add a link in this comment box..

Comment: @AmanjotKaur its here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818488/how-to-make-percentage-filling-up-with-jquery-js

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly something like this could work: 
You have to use `.each()` to define your function for each `.skill` element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.skill').each(function() {

    var skillBar = $(this).find('.inner');
    var skillVal = skillBar.attr("data-progress");
    $(skillBar).animate({
      height: skillVal
    }, 2100);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skill">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" data-progress="100%">
      <h2 id="demo">€0</h2>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No I want to get rid of button. I just want to make it work when page is loaded. Button was for testing if its working but now if I remove and modify something it does not work itself alone

Comment: then remove the button and use only `$('skill').each()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="skill">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner" data-progress="100%">
<h2 id="demo">€0</h2>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var skillBar = $(this).siblings().find('.inner');
    var skillVal = skillBar.attr("data-progress");
    $(skillBar).animate({  height: skillVal}, 2100);
});
</script>
```

So i was trying to make it work like this. So I would not need button to make script work.

Comment: Adar, plz have a look at my answer.

Comment: This does not **answer** the question.  Please edit the question if you had additional information to add.